# Why does size_pizza != "S" or "M" or "L" only continue if you enter S

Tags: python

I need to write a code which allow you to order a pizza but if you enter something else then S (small) or M (medium) or L (large) it has to return you that question. but the problem is that if you type S it continues but if you enter M or L it returns the same question (which not should happen)

I tried to put a block before the while and I tried to put it on different lines.

```py
Size_pizza = str(input("Which size do you want your pizza to be? Small(S), medium (M) of Large (L)"))
while Size_pizza != "K" or "M" or "G":
    Size_pizza = str(input("Which size do you want your pizza to be? Small(S), medium (M) of Large (L)"))
```

if you enter S or M or L it has to continue with the code but it only continues if you enter S.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: FYI you should always tag with the actual language that you're using as an absolute minimum; it generally doesn't matter where you're running it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the input is "S", "M", or "L", then your while loop should have a statement to check if the input is not "S", "M", or "L".

```
Size_pizza = str(input("Which size do you want your pizza to be?)) 
while Size_pizza != "S" or Size_pizza != "M" or Size_pizza != "L":
        Size_pizza = str(input("Which size do you want your pizza to be?))
```

Note that you have to say Size_pizza != "S" or Size_pizza != "M" or Size_pizza != "L".... not just Size_pizza != "S" or "M" or "L".

Comment: you forgot " after 'Which size do you want your pizza to be' and because of that in the next line strings look like not strings and other things like strings

Answer (score 0):

`Size_pizza != "K" or "M" or "G"` will always evaluate to `True`, because even if the first part of alternative is `False`, the rest will always evaluate to `True` - `"M"` and `"G"` are always `True`, because they're non-empty strings.

To make it work as intended, there are two possible ways to fix:

```
while Size_pizza != "S" or Size_pizza != "M" or Size_pizza != "L":
    ...
```

or

```
while Size_pizza not in ("S", "M", "L"):
    ...
```

I'd prefer the second one since it's more compact.